# navigation in UITableView in monotouch iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, syntax, navigation, xamarin.ios

i am new to `iPad` developer,

i have created two or three `iPad` application in objective c using `Xcode 4.`

but now i want to create `iPad` application using `Monodeveloper` tool in `C#` language...

in which, i want to do `navigation`,

when user selects any row of `UITableVIew`, on selection of row of tableView i want to navigate to a new Page..

i searched in google but i didn't got any syntax.

***Any help will be appreciated.***

***Thanks In Advance !!***

Comment: there is a wealth of documentation on the [Xamarin site](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios), as well as sample apps, at least 5 published books on MonoTouch, many blogs, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `UITableView` should be fairly identical to your previous ObjectiveC applications, i.e. you need to override the selected method and push your new view.

However there's a **much** simpler way of doing tables using MonoTouch, it's called **[MonoTouch.Dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog)** and it is now bundled with MonoTouch 5.2 (and more recent) releases.

There's a very complete sample application on [github](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/tree/master/Sample) that will show you how to use most features and a great [video tutorial](http://blog.xamarin.com/2012/02/10/easily-create-ios-user-interfaces-with-monotouch-dialog/) from Xamarin's Seminars.